# How to query the number of records when there is the DISTINCT keyword in the SQL multi-table join query string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server and my SQL command is:

```
select distinct 
    table_motor.motor_ID, table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID 
from 
    table_motor, 
    table_welding_machine, 
    table_joint_point_para, 
    table_motor_production_line 
where 
    table_joint_point_para.welding_machine_ID = table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID 
    and table_joint_point_para.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and table_motor_production_line.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and 1=1
```

There are 83 records in the result.

My question is : how to query the number of records when there is the `DISTINCT` keyword in the SQL multi-table joint query string?

If I use count in the string, I got the error:

> Column table_motor.motor_ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqiC6.png)

If I change my SQL command like this, I do not get the total number of record:

```
select distinct 
    table_motor.motor_ID, 
    table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID, 
    count(*) 
from 
    table_motor, 
    table_welding_machine, 
    table_joint_point_para, 
    table_motor_production_line 
where 
    table_joint_point_para.welding_machine_ID = table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID 
    and table_joint_point_para.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and table_motor_production_line.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and 1=1
group by 
    table_motor.motor_ID, table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeqHK.png)

How to solve this problem?

this string is OK:

```
select count(distinct (t_test01.tid)) from t_test01, t_test02 where t_test01.tid = t_test02.tid
```

this string is error : Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
select count(distinct (t_test01.tid, t_test02.value)) from t_test01, t_test02 where t_test01.tid = t_test02.tid
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and what is your expected result?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` doesn't do anything. You are already grouping the data and will get only 1 record for each of the `DISTINCT` columns in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: The red count is not an error, it's simply indicating that it is a function

Comment: Also, try grouping with only one of the attributes (for example, only table_motor.motor_ID)

Comment: sample data is shown in result image. I want the  total number of record(83). such as : select count(*) from table1, the result is  total number of record.

Comment: select count(distinct value) from t_test : OK;   select count(distinct table_motor.motor_ID, table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID) ... error : Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your query in a common table expression and then count on this CTE:

```
WITH cte_count
AS
(
select distinct 
    table_motor.motor_ID, table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID 
from 
    table_motor, 
    table_welding_machine, 
    table_joint_point_para, 
    table_motor_production_line 
where 
    table_joint_point_para.welding_machine_ID = table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID 
    and table_joint_point_para.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and table_motor_production_line.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and 1=1
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte_count;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It gives the total number of records, but I suspect that there will be efficiency problems. My current method is not efficient, in order to display the total number,  I have to query all the records first before every paging query.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
    select * , count(*) as CountOfRecords from (
select distinct 
    table_motor.motor_ID, 
    table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID
    
from 
    table_motor, 
    table_welding_machine, 
    table_joint_point_para, 
    table_motor_production_line 
where 
    table_joint_point_para.welding_machine_ID = table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID 
    and table_joint_point_para.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and table_motor_production_line.motor_ID = table_motor.motor_ID 
    and 1=1
group by 
    table_motor.motor_ID, table_welding_machine.welding_machine_ID
) as d group by d.motor_ID, d.welding_machine_ID
```

Comment: thanks for reply. it also gives 3 columns as result image shown, and the third column is all 1. I want the total number of record. such as : select count(*) from table, it will gives the total number

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a windowed `COUNT(*) OVER ()` to get the total number of rows**

```sql
select distinct 
    m.motor_ID, wm.welding_machine_ID,
    total_count = COUNT(*) OVER ()
from 
     table_joint_point_para jpp
join table_welding_machine wm on jpp.welding_machine_ID = wm.welding_machine_ID
join table_motor m on jpp.motor_ID = m.motor_ID
join table_motor_production_line mpl on mpl.motor_ID = m.motor_ID;
```

Note that I have used proper join syntax, which was introduced *30 years ago*, as well as aliases.

Comment: thanks for reply. the result has 83 records like this :                                                   
1999-1031055                             AE026048                                 224